# Multiselected rows in datatables, how to get one column data from JSON to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, post

I'm getting in jQuery object and I want to pass it through php. I'm trying to get one cell from multiple rows of my populated table with datatables plugin.

I basically want to select multiple user and send them an e-mail. I have one column in my datatables that are e-mails. I'm pretty much new at this and tried many things but no result.

So I'm able to get my jQuery object

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tbl_contacts = $('#tbl_contacts').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons:[
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'selectAll', 'selectNone'
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'multi'
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value="">Tous les syndicats</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }               
    } );

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
    $('#sendemail').click(function(){
       var data = tbl_contacts.rows('.selected').data();
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I'm getting this in my console:

> 0: (7) ["1", "2147483647", "test1", "", "", "", ""]
>
> 1: (7) ["2", "13570477865e7937023cbe43.26502462", "test some id", "", "", "", ""]
>
> 2: (7) ["2", "699674795e793702417b57.37923011", "test some id", "", "", "", ""]

I want to post the second column of each row witch is the userid through my PHP file to query it. I just can't figure out how to POST the value from JSON to PHP to be able to loop through the userid of selected rows.

My action buttons is:

```
<div>                    
<a  id="sendemail" class="btn btn-success float-left" method="post" href="send_email.php">Send email</a>
</div>



Thanks ahead of time for the help.
```

Comment: Can you add some more information (e.g. a link) to the plugin, you're using, so that others can comprehend how the snippet works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's send your data as an array by ajax that you could access by PHP :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tbl_contacts = $('#tbl_contacts').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons:[
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'selectAll', 'selectNone'
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'multi'
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value="">Tous les syndicats</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }               
    } );

    $('#tbl_contacts tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
 

 $('#sendemail').click(function(){
  var data = tbl_contacts.rows('.selected').data();
  var arr = $.makeArray( data );

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {email:arr},
   url: "send_email.php",

  })
 });

});
```

```css
table.dataTable{width:100%;margin:0 auto;clear:both;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable tfoot th{font-weight:bold}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable thead td{padding:10px 18px;border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead th:active,table.dataTable thead td:active{outline:none}table.dataTable tfoot th,table.dataTable tfoot td{padding:10px 18px 6px 18px;border-top:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead .sorting,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center right}table.dataTable thead .sorting{background-image:url("../images/sort_both.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable tbody tr{background-color:#ffffff}table.dataTable tbody tr.selected{background-color:#B0BED9}table.dataTable tbody th,table.dataTable tbody td{padding:8px 10px}table.dataTable.row-border tbody th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody td,table.dataTable.display tbody th,table.dataTable.display tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-right:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr th:first-child,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr td:first-child{border-left:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd{background-color:#f9f9f9}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected{background-color:#acbad4}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover{background-color:#f6f6f6}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected{background-color:#aab7d1}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_3{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1{background-color:#f1f1f1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2{background-color:#f3f3f3}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3{background-color:whitesmoke}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a6b4cd}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a8b5cf}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a9b7d1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_1{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_2{background-color:#fcfcfc}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_3{background-color:#fefefe}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#aebcd6}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#afbdd8}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1{background-color:#eaeaea}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2{background-color:#ececec}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3{background-color:#efefef}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a2aec7}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a3b0c9}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a5b2cb}table.dataTable.no-footer{border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable.nowrap th,table.dataTable.nowrap td{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable.compact thead th,table.dataTable.compact thead td{padding:4px 17px 4px 4px}table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,table.dataTable.compact tfoot td{padding:4px}table.dataTable.compact tbody th,table.dataTable.compact tbody td{padding:4px}table.dataTable th.dt-left,table.dataTable td.dt-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable th.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty{text-align:center}table.dataTable th.dt-right,table.dataTable td.dt-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable th.dt-justify,table.dataTable td.dt-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-center,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-nowrap,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable,table.dataTable th,table.dataTable td{box-sizing:content-box}.dataTables_wrapper{position:relative;clear:both;*zoom:1;zoom:1}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length{float:left}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:right;text-align:right}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input{margin-left:0.5em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info{clear:both;float:left;padding-top:0.755em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:right;text-align:right;padding-top:0.25em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#333 !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover{color:#333 !important;border:1px solid #979797;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active{cursor:default;color:#666 !important;border:1px solid transparent;background:transparent;box-shadow:none}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover{color:white !important;border:1px solid #111;background-color:#585858;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active{outline:none;background-color:#2b2b2b;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2b2b2b), color-stop(100%, #0c0c0c));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #111}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .ellipsis{padding:0 1em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;width:100%;height:40px;margin-left:-50%;margin-top:-25px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;font-size:1.2em;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{color:#333}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll{clear:both}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody{*margin-top:-1px;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>th,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>td,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>th,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>td{vertical-align:middle}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>th>div.dataTables_sizing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>td>div.dataTables_sizing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>th>div.dataTables_sizing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>td>div.dataTables_sizing{height:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody{border-bottom:1px solid #111}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table.dataTable,.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody>table{border-bottom:none}.dataTables_wrapper:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;content:"";clear:both;height:0}@media screen and (max-width: 767px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{margin-top:0.5em}}@media screen and (max-width: 640px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{margin-top:0.5em}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table data-order='[[ 0, "asc" ]]' id="tbl_contacts" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Numero</th>
                <th>Nom Prenom</th>
                <th>Adresse</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Code postal</th>
                <th>Commune</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>mail1@zen</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>mail2@zen</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>                    
<a  id="sendemail" class="btn btn-success float-left" href="#">Send email</a>
</div>
</body>
```

The PHP code is quite simple :

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['email'] as $ligne) {
    echo $ligne[3]."\n";
    //Here comes the send mail function.
}
```

Note that the [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) doesn't know the `method` attribute.

Comment: Seems to be working thanks. The thing I'm trying to wrap my head arround is how to access the array in my PHP file heres my button `<a  id="sendemail" class="btn btn-success float-left" method="post">Send email</a>` Then i guess I place an if satatement with isset($_POST['sendmail')). Thank you once againe

Comment: Glad if my answer could help you. Could you click on the check mark beside the answer then ?

Comment: Can you help me with PHP side?

Comment: I have updated my code and added the PHP code to get the mail list.

Comment: I'm getting this error when i run the php \Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\ezbManager\send_email.php on line 2

Comment: I think I got it. So the .ajax()  POST is sending a request to my PHP file that will process the information. Then that information is sent back and can be diplayed, for example, in a input field in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: Everything is working fine so I added
        `.done(function(data){
            $('#modal_sendemail').modal('show');
            $('#emailto').append('<input value="'+data+'"/>');
            console.log(data);
        })` My eamil adress are poping up in an <input> in my email modal where i can wright my message. Thanks a bunch you are a time saver.